# ¿Cómo homogeneizar un texto (quitar tildes)?

Tags: r, text

Me gustaría saber si existe algún paquete/función que permita homogeneizar texto, si por ejemplo tengo:

```
a <- c("Mesa", "Jabón", "piedra", "césar")
```

Una función que me devolviese

```
b <- function(a);b
[1] "MESA"   "JABON"  "PIEDRA" "CESAR"
```

De modo que me generalizase el texto poniéndolo todo en mayúsculas y sin tildes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si solo buscas llevar el código a mayúsculas, puedes hacer:

```
toupper(a)
[1] "MESA"   "JABÓN"  "PIEDRA" "CÉSAR"
```

También quieres quitar los acentos, podrías usar `chartr()`:

```
chartr("ÁÉÍÓÚ", "AEIOU", toupper(a))
[1] "MESA"   "JABON"  "PIEDRA" "CESAR"
```

pero intuyo quetal vez te interese transformar cualquier otro tipo de acento, por lo que, me parece mejor hacer una conversión de codificación para llevar los caracteres a una tabla más acotada como la ASCII. Para eso puedes usar una rutina muy útil del paquete `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)
a <- c("Mesa", "Jabón", "piedra", "césar", "cigüeña")
toupper(stri_trans_general(a,"Latin-ASCII"))
[1] "MESA"    "JABON"   "PIEDRA"  "CESAR"   "CIGUENA"
```